# Chat database overloading (HTML, PHP, JS)

Tags: php, html

Probably the main issue, is that I'm new to all of this kind of coding. But here is what is going on:

Users can type messages into a chat box and their message is sent to a database. Every second, all of the message data that is in the database is re-displayed for each user in session (to update if there was any new messages) -- this causes my site to very quickly become unresponsive and "break".

I've been trying to think up a way to only append "new" messages, but how do you track what is "new" to each user without creating duplicates etc.

I'm very new to this, so I'm looking for a basic idea that I can use to build off of. The best way isn't always the most intuitive for new people...

Any help is appreciated!

@Matt 
Good way to get time?

```
$date = date_create();
$timestamp =  date_timestamp_get($date);
$human_time = gmdate("Y-m-d\ i:s", $timestamp);
```

Comment: Keep another table with users last sync time. When a user device asks for new massages, check to see when they last sunc from the database, and only send them messages that have been changes / added since their lat sync.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! Thats a damn good idea. I actually already have a column in the "messages" table that is a timestamp, however it is shows my messages are from 2012, and the time is wrong lol. Is this a proper way to get time?

Comment: In PHP you can simply use [`time`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php); then in MySQL, use [`any of these`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have better scenario to display the messages

For example

if the last message > 30 seconds

check if there's new messages every 10, 20 or 30 seconds depends on your need

if last message > 5 seconds  so the writing base is slow

refresh the messages everything 5 seconds  and so on

like this one

```
var nextRequest = 1000;

        // 2 seconds
        if(chat.data.noActivity > 3){
            nextRequest = 2000;
        }

        if(chat.data.noActivity > 10){
            nextRequest = 5000;
        }

        // 15 seconds
        if(chat.data.noActivity > 20){
            nextRequest = 15000;
        }

        setTimeout(callback,nextRequest);
```

or better then all of this  use Socket.IO   they have chat example as you need.